# Why does my hash function fail with "ArithmeticException integer overflow" even when using unchecked math

Tags: clojure, integer-arithmetic

I am using the following function to try to create a 64-bit hash of a string, but it is failing with an ArithmeticException even though I am using the "unchecked" version of the arithmetic operators.

```
user> (reduce (fn [h c]
                (unchecked-add (unchecked-multiply h 31) (long c)))
              1125899906842597
              "hello")
ArithmeticException integer overflow   clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a hint here:

for whatever reason the first param in a function here is treated as integer. Adding type hint helps to solve this problem:

```
user> (reduce (fn [^long h c]
                (unchecked-add (unchecked-multiply h 31) (long c)))
              1125899906842597
              "hello")
7096547112155234317
```

**update:**
moreover: it looks that it comes from the `unchecked-multiply`

```
user> (reduce (fn [h c]
                (unchecked-add (unchecked-multiply ^long h 31) (long c)))
              1125899906842597
              "hello")
7096547112155234317
```

*i will make some additional research, and update here, in case of any new information*

**update 2:**
ok, that's what i've found out:

looking at the clojure's documentation at https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java
we can see the following:

our case

```
static public Number unchecked_multiply(Object x, long y){return multiply(x,y);}
```

leads to:

```
static public Number multiply(Object x, long y){
    return multiply(x,(Object)y);
}
```

then:

```
static public Number multiply(Object x, Object y){
    return ops(x).combine(ops(y)).multiply((Number)x, (Number)y);
}
```

so at the end it calls `multiply` method from `LongOps` inner class.

```
final public Number multiply(Number x, Number y){
    return num(Numbers.multiply(x.longValue(), y.longValue()));
}
```

so finally it leads us to a simple (checked?) multiply:

```
static public long multiply(long x, long y){
  if (x == Long.MIN_VALUE && y < 0)
        return throwIntOverflow();
    long ret = x * y;
    if (y != 0 && ret/y != x)
        return throwIntOverflow();
    return ret;
}
```

**kaboom!**

so i don't know whether it is a bug or the desired behavior, but it looks really weird to me.

so the only thing i could advice, is to always remember to typehint your values when using unchecked math in clojure.

Comment: a `(println h c)` here also might help to see whats going on (h is growing)

Comment: Thanks. I got caught in the web of clojure.lang.Numbers myself. Nice catch. It certainly looks like a bug to me - but I'm no expert.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behaviour you want by avoiding the function calls:

```
(loop [h 1125899906842597
       cs "hello"]
  (let [c (first cs)]
    (if c
      (recur (unchecked-add (unchecked-multiply h 31) (long c))
             (rest cs))
      h)))

;7096547112155234317
```

Why this is so, I don't know.

Comment: that is probably because `h` here is obviously a number, and the compiler is smart enough to see that, while in a function the type of the parameter without a hint is considered to be the Object.

Comment: @leetwinski Yes. The puzzle is not why this works, but why the questioner's version doesn't. Why should a boxed `long`be regarded as a boxed `int`? [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33307530/1562315) makes a good case that this is a bug.

Comment: It's not considered a boxed int, the method just calls throwIntOverflow, while both operands are long.